# Can I have a speech recognition on Firefox?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, cross-browser, voice-recognition

I currently have for my web application a speech recognition functionality achieved with a `Speech Recognition` library named `annyang`. This works only in chrome because `x-webkit-speech`(which is used for speech recognition) works only for Chrome.

My question here is if I can do something(even if I have to do radical changes) to have a speech recognition functionality in Mozilla Firefox too (and eventually in IE).

Comment: Are you still using x-webkit-speech? Isn't that deprecated? What replacement have you found?

Comment: @Nilay Vishwakarma That was just for a school project and for my personal interests. I stopped working on that project a while ago and I didn't look for a replacement. Sorry.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Looks like they're working on it:  https://wiki.mozilla.org/SpeechAPI#Technical_Stuff

...but that it's not coming any time soon:  http://caniuse.com/web-speech

Looks like you'll need to stick with Chrome for the time being.